# Stronger Physical Connection to GPIO Pins

Tags: gpio, connection

I looked a fair bit for a discussion on how people physically connect to the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins, but could not find too many resources. I use my Pi's in vibration intensive, remote locations so having a dupont cable fall off the GPIO pin is a disaster.

I started to use screw on terminal hats like:
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2711 and https://www.seeedstudio.com/GPIO-Screw-Terminal-Hat-for-Raspberry-Pi-p-4808.html and found these to be generally better than ordinary dupont connectors in terms of rarely getting disconnected. Being able to use thicker wires makes the wire itself also less likely to tear.

However, I wanted to ask: **how do others who need them ensure strong connections?**

(I did consider soldering, but personally have a really hard time not overlapping pins)

Comment: not really pi specific

Comment: If vibration is an issue you will have issues with other connectors. In any permanent product I wouldn't use dupont cables but a proper 40 pin IDC header.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ribbon cable instead of dupont cables, and use a latching pin header to keep the cable from unplugging.

[image]

Comment: How do you prepare the ribbon to pin it without soldering? I'm trying to take the Pi in a sandwich between two latching pin headers, but at the end of the day, I still rely on dupont connectors on top of the headers...

Comment: the connector crimps onto the ribbon cable ... you can see the contacts that cut through the insulation and make a connection with the wires in this picture ... https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1WFSXNFXXXXbhXFXXq6xXFXXXC/50-Pcs-Per-Lot-2-54mm-Pitch-2x25-Pin-50-Pin-Male-Header-IDC-Ribbon-Cable.jpg .... use a vise or parallel jaw pliers to crimp ... the connector shell has grooves to guide each wire in the cable